# Is there a way to inline a Unicode escape sequence?

Tags: bash, unicode, hex, sh, zsh

This works:

```
ghost=$'\U1F47B'
PROMPT='time: %T $ghost > '
```

But is there a way to inline the hexadecimal version of the Unicode character?

Comment: Here is one solution that I found:
`PROMPT="time: %T "$'\U1F47B'" > "`

Comment: You can put anything you want inside `$'...'`; they are just like single quotes, but they recognize some escape sequences: `PROMPT='time: %T \U1F47B > '`.

Comment: @chepner: I think you meant `PROMPT=$'time: %T \U1F47B > '`. But unfortunately comments can't be edited. I reopened the question so you can answer; the dupe is useful but not precise.

Comment: Also: `bash` and `zsh` are two different shells; I can tell from your use of `PROMPT` that you are actually using `zsh`. Although my answer applies to both shells, it's rarely useful to tag a question with both, as it's possible that you would need separate answers to address each shell.

Answer (score 6):

The contents of `$'...'` are not restricted to its special escape sequences. Such sequences are simply recognized when inside `$'...'`; you can include other text as well, since they are otherwise identical to single quotes (i.e., no parameter expansion).

```
PROMPT=$'time: %T \U1F47B > '
```

Comment: @rici Thanks; I can't seem to type a coherent answer to this question :)